# Google Cloud - BigQuery - PHP use proxy

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I created a PHP script to retrieve some datas from my Google Cloud Platform account. Below is how I did :

```
<?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json');
    $projectId = 'xxxxx';
    $datasetId = 'xxxxxx';
    $table = 'xxxxx';

    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId
    ]);

    // etc...
```

Everything works fine on my local computer (WAMP) but when I migrate my script to my company production environment, there is a problem :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException' with message 'cURL
>   error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com'

In fact I was excepting this message because every time I use Curl, I need to set our company proxy info :

```
<?php

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx');
```

By the way, i'm 100% sure that googleapis.com is white-listed by our proxies... but how to do it with the `BigQueryClient` ? I searched in the official documentation, no way to find how to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing blindly these constructions to one of the connection builder classes, hopefully one picks this up

```
'restOptions' => [
            'proxy', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    ]
```

on the other hand if you have a trace log you could see if Guzzle or something else is used. Consider opening an issue tracking at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/issues

Comment: Thanks for reply. It does'nt work :s If Guzzle is used, how to set my proxy configuration in my script ?

Comment: try `restOptions`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/Core/src/RequestWrapper.php#L63

Comment: Ok, I don't understand how to use it. But I created a new "issue" on the Google github.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery uses www.googleapis.com as its [endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/#top_of_page).
The command line instructions have [global flags](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#global_flags) to specify an address, password, port and user name regarding a proxy usage, however, for client libraries you'll need to verify the access with your infrastructure team.

Answer (score 0):

Use php's putenv() to set the proxy before using BigQueryClient.

```
putenv('HTTPS_PROXY=192.168.1.1:8080');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

$guzzleClient = new Client();
$config = [
    'projectId' => 'xxx',
    'keyFilePath' => 'key_path',
    'restOptions' => [
        'proxy' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx'
    ],
    'authHttpHandler' => function (RequestInterface $request, array $options = []) use ($guzzleClient) {
        return $guzzleClient->send(
            $request,
            $options + [
                'proxy' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx'
            ]
        );
    }
];

$bigQueryClient = new BigQueryClient($config);
```

It works for me with php library google/cloud-bigquery version 1.8.0